# strongloop loopback id getting sent to the user owning the object

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a strongloop app in which I am trying to post some data to my REST APIs and then trying to retrieve it from another user but I am not getting the "id" of that record to the user not owning the object. How do I access the generated "id" from the user not owning the object. There are no ACLs in my model file

I am expecting the generated unique user identifiers to be returned along with the json response, for example if I make a request like this -

```
http://localhost:80/api/tuitions?access_token=qvpvtsbWOLZYydUDcbO0VP6YrlfHhbURHpkvPjnUyU9wRHpclAyJh44RKJ6VU36x
```

the output is -

```
[
  {
    "area": [
      "901"
    ],
    "city": "9",
    "class": "9",
    "subjects": [
      "902"
    ],
    "userId": "5696915dec62196433db7950",
    "created": "2016-01-14T18:40:07.761Z",
    "updated": "2016-01-14T18:40:07.761Z",
    "identifier": "5697eb8767e585347755c23b"
  }
]
```

in my loopback explorer and my loopback tuition model file defines identifier as -

```
{
  "name": "tuition",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    // ...
    "identifier": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

But when I make the same request with my Angular App in my controller with something like -

```
Tuition.find({
      filter: {
        order: 'created DESC'
      }
    }).$promise;
```

I get this -

```
[{"area":["901"],"city":"9","class":"9","subjects":["902"],"userId":"5696915dec62196433db7950","created":"2016-01-14T18:40:07.761Z","updated":"2016-01-14T18:40:07.761Z"}]
```

which does not have `identifier`

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to. Can you post an example model, relationship, and API endpoint along with what data you expect to get back?

Comment: @jakerella updated the question with the expected model info, required request and response structure.

Comment: Hmm... my guess is that the Angular app is somehow grabbing the property identified as the `id` (because of `"id": true` in the model config) and moving it around. I'd recommend posting this on the [Angular SDK Github repo](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-angular) as an issue and see what you get.

Comment: But, I am getting the `identifier` populated with the _id from the mongodb if I am logged in as the user who posted the object. so I am thinking it may be because of some inbuilt ACL that prevents exposing the `_id` to the users not owning the object. If you think this might be correct, can you point me in the direction as to how I can debug this ? If this does not work I would create an issue and see what I can get

Comment: meanwhile for the time being is there any other way to post new data to methods like `Tuition.application.create()` where Tuition and Application are related models with `hasMany` relationship. so that's why I need the `Id` to pass it as the query parameter. so are there any other ways for doing this ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why the `identifier` property wouldn't come through when logged in as a different user. I think this could be a bug and I would recommend submitting an issue on Github.